# Android: Creating custom RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

I have this view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I want to create a custom subclass of RelativeLayout that every added item is this view, adding them would be like this: `myCustomRelativeLayout.addItem("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", marginTop, height)`, how do I do this?

Here's what it would look like if I added 3 views like this:

```
myCustomRelativeLayout.addItem("left1", "left one", "right1","right one", o, 200);
myCustomRelativeLayout.addItem("left2", "left two", "right2","right two", 150, 200);
myCustomRelativeLayout.addItem("left3", "left three", "right3","right three", 350, 200);
```

I'm not an expert, detailed explanations are welcomed

Comment: could you provide more explanation ? like adding representative images.

Comment: Note that a frame layout can have only one child

Comment: @kaanyılmaz please see edited question.

Comment: @F43nd1r frame layout can host more than one child, although it may not be easy to organize them

Comment: OK, let me correct: a frame layout *should* have only one child.

Comment: @F43nd1r Some views may need to overlay, what do you suggest instead?

Comment: A RelativeLayout looks good based on what I can see from your code. It allows overlays and provides easier ways to position children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a custom view with those texts and just add that custom view into another layout:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener{

public TextView ClassName, Room, StartingTime, EndingTime;
public float Size;
public RelativeLayout mContainer;

// constructor
public CustomView (Context context, String subject, String room, String startingTime, String endingTime, int background, double size) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
    ClassName.setText(subject );
    Room.setText(room );
    StartingTime.setText(startingTime);
    EndingTime.setText(endingTime);
    mContainer.setBackgroundColor(background);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)size);
    params.setMargins(3,0,3,0);
    mContainer.setLayoutParams(params2); 
}


private void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this, true);

    this.mContainer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ClassContainer);
    this.ClassName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theClassName);
    this.Room = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theClassRoom);
    this.StartingTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theClassStartingTime);
    this.EndingTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theClassEndingTime);
}
```

Create one like this:

```
CustomView mClass = new Schedule_Class_mini(getActivity(),
                                "Math",
                                "Room 8",
                                "10:30",
                                "12:00",
                                Color.parseColor("#508ACCA4"),
                                150);

Container.addView(mClass, params);
```